# Redemption - Find public folder

Tags: delphi, outlook, exchange-server, outlook-redemption

Using Redemption I need to put a draft email in a specific Public Folder. I know the full path of the folder but I can't work out how to get there using RDO. Eg. the folder path is "\\Public Folders\All Public Folders\XXXX\Drafts"

I'm using Delphi2006 and Exchange 2007 but that shouldn't matter...

```
oSession := CreateOleObject('Redemption.RDOSession');
oSession.LogonExchangeMailbox('xxxxx@xxxxxx.co.uk','ServerName');
oStore := oSession.Stores.FindExchangePublicFoldersStore;
```

Any pointers on how to get from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `oSession.GetFolderFromPath` . You don't even need to find the PF store first.

See http://dimastr.com/redemption/rdo/rdosession.htm for documentation of the `RDOSession` object.